# Check for empty data file (only header) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

What is the most elegant (and/or Pythonic) way to check that a data file has only a header before using `numpy.loadtxt` or `numpy.genfromtxt` to load columns of data into numpy arrays?

I have a quantum Monte Carlo code which writes headers to disk upon execution and sometimes never writes data (wallclock of cluster being used).  I have obviously written Python scripts to deal with a large number of data files at once, and sometimes a few of the files end up never having data written to them in the allotted time.  I need to let my analysis scripts tell when the files are empty before I try to load in the data and perform certain operations on it.

My method (which works, but maybe isn't the most elegant) is by calling a function that looks like

```
def checkIfEmpty(fName,n):
    '''
    takes the first non-header line number and returns true or false
    depending upon whether that line is blank or not.
    '''
    Empty = False
    fp = open(fName)
    numLines=0
    for line in fp:
        numLines += 1
    fp.close()

    if n==numLines:
        Empty=True

    return Empty
```

Comment: You could check to see if there's a second "line" (whether that's after comments etc...)... but in what context are you wanting to use this?

Comment: @JonClements see my edit.  I just want something that will tell whether a file has only a header (always begins with #) and no actual data written.

Comment: You iterate over all the lines before you decide if it is empty or not, which might be a waste of time if your file is long. Depending on your file format, you should try to decide this immediately after your header and then stop directly. And if you want to be more pythonic, you might try to use a with-statement for opening the file, that seems common practice these days.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Since you've indicated the output files may not really be that much bigger than the header-only files, I've thought of a different way to rid yourself of the explicit for loop.

```
def checkIfEmpty(fname, n):
    # NOTE: n is the file byte position at the end of the header.
    file_open = open( fname, 'r' )
    EOH = file_open.seek(n)
    if len(file_open.read()) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Wherever you calculate n in your code currently, you would just return the byte position. open_file.tell() will return this value, if you've read in lines somewhere else to test your header.

END EDIT

How much data is usually in the file?

If there's a huge difference in the file size if the data is missing you could use:

```
import os
def checkIfEmpty(fname, header_cutoff):
    if os.path.getsize( fname ) < header_cutoff:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Another reason I would prefer this solution is that with alot of large files, opening and checking them could be slow.

Comment: The data files get rather large sometimes, but in this case there is usually not an issue with empty files.  And yeah I need to modify the above function to break the for loop after the comment lines.

Comment: So is there not a big enough difference in file size for you to simply check the file size without iterating over the file at all?

Comment: The code outputs ~ 10 different types of output files, each of which has a different sized header.  I would like the function to be more robust than to check the file size.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion.  The MC code may only write say, 1 line of data for a fairly time consuming simulation.  This type of thing is not robust enough for my purposes.

Comment: In that case the way I would do it is approximately what you've already done; except I would break the loop. A different option similar to my original would be to use file.seek() to jump to the end of the header, and then file.read() to test if there's anything left. It would return 0 if you're at the end of the file. It avoids the explicit for loop which by definition makes it more elegant and/or pythonic :)

Comment: I edited my answer to include the file.seek() and file.read() version of checkIfEmpty()

Comment: for my code, n is the number of comment lines in the header file.  Is this the case for your edit as well?

Comment: No. n would be the byte position of the end of the header. When you're finished reading the header lines, if you do n=file.tell(), you should receive the byte position at the end of your header.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
def is_header_only(fname):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        return next(fin, '').lstrip().startswith('#') and next(fin, None) is None
```